# Display hours format 24h in FullCalendar

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar in Drupal 7.

I'm trying to make a weekly calendar with available hours, I'm having problems with the 24h schedule, the hours that should be 13:00 show only 13, without the: 00, 13:20 works normally, only the: 00 does not show.

I'm using Axis format like this: H (: mm)

Attached is some images for better understanding, could anyone help me?

Problem in FullCalendar.

[image: Problem in FullCalendar]

Config in Views of Drupal 7.
[image: Config in Views of Drupal 7]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use

```
HH:mm
```

for a full 24-hr format.

`H(:mm)`, which you've got now, means that

- you see single digit hours in the early hours (0, 1, 2 instead of 00,
  01, 02 etc ), and
- the brackets indicate that the minutes should not be visible when they're zero (`00`).

See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/utilities/date_formatting_string and https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format for more details of the formatting strings and what options you can set.

Comment: That's it! Yes, you did.
Thank you very much @ADyson